# primeng: How to find particular value in selectItem array using code

Tags: primeng

Please help me out on how to find an particular value in primeng SelectItem[] array.

I have selectItem array as below.

```
  this.cities = [];
  this.cities.push({label:'Select ', value:null});
  this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}});
  this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}});
```

I wanted to find the particular item({id:5,name:'Paris',code:'PRS'}) from above list. or i just wanted to find the item with the code 'PRS' only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the following methods. But the best method is '**find**'.

**Finding the item with the value {id:5,name:'Paris',code:'PRS'}**

```
let obj = {id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'};
var x = this.cities.find(item => 
    JSON.stringify(item.value) === JSON.stringify(obj)
);

console.log(x);
```

OR

```
let obj = {id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'};
this.cities.forEach((item,key) => {
    if(item && JSON.stringify(item.value) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
        console.log("Item found at location : "+key)
    }
});
```

**Finding the item with the code 'PRS'**

```
this.cities.forEach((item,key) => {
    if(item && item.value != null && item.value.code == 'PRS') {
        console.log("Item found at location : "+key)
    }
});
```